# Angularjs ng-show for table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a button to show up only when there's a table in ng-view.
How do i code it to do that? How should the condition be written to achieve that? 
Thanks for the help in advance!

HTML:

```
<main ng-view>
</main>
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tableToCsv')" type="button contact- 
button" class="btnDL" ng-show="toDLTable()">XLSX Download</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

ControllerCode

```
$scope.x = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
```

In HTML

```
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tableToCsv')" type="button contact- 
button" class="btnDL" ng-if="x.length>0" ng-show="toDLTable()">XLSX Download</button>
```

Comment: It works at first, but after i go to a page with table and to another page with no table, the button's still there.

Comment: $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $scope.x.length=0;
        });

add this in the controller inn which table is

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to have a div to identify,

```
<div class="view-container">
    <main  ng-view>
    </main>
</div>
```

Now inside your controller,

```
$scope.CheckContent = function(){
   var theView = document.getElementsByClassName("view-container")[0].getElementById("myView").getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
   if(theView != null && theView == ''){
      $scope.showTab = true;
   }
  }
}
```

and bind it in HTML

```
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tableToCsv')" type="button contact- 
button" class="btnDL" ng-show="showTab">XLSX Download</button>
```

Comment: The button not showing @Sajeetharan
Theres no error on console log either

Comment: you might need to alter the code according to the table name

Comment: What is $scope.CheckContent and what is myView referring to? I am not good at angularjs @@ so it would be good if you could explain it to me

Comment: $scope.checkContent is the method you need to call in the template and theView refers to the table name. Just debug to see what you get there